# writing strings that have quotes correctly in python

Tags: python, yaml, escaping

I have a Dockerfile that contains lines like:

```
LABEL "com.datadoghq.ad.logs"='[{"source": "mysource", "name": "myservicename"}]'
```

I have a python script that I want to read grab this LABEL value(everything after "LABEL" and add that to yaml file.  Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import yaml

def _extract_dockerfile_labels():
    labels = []
    with open("testing/dockerfile") as dockerfile:
        for line in dockerfile.readlines():
            if line.startswith('LABEL'):
                label_val = line.replace("LABEL ","", 1)
                labels.append(label_val.rstrip()). # rstrip() gets rid of the newline
    with open("output.yml", "w+") as out_file:
        yaml.dump(labels, out_file, default_flow_style=False)

_extract_dockerfile_labels()
```

The outfile looks like this:

```
- '"com.datadoghq.ad.logs"=''[{"source": "mysource", "name": "myservicename"}]'''
```

What I need for that to look like is:

```
- "com.datadoghq.ad.logs"='[{"source": "mysource", "name": "myservicename"}]'
```

How can I make this work without adding extra quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that you are using `yaml.dump()` function for output, which outputs object as YAML document. It YAML notation strings have quotes.
For standart python output try using `out_file.write(labels)`, closing file afterwards.
Note, that your string is not parsed as a dictionary currently, and so is interpretated as a plain string. So if you intended parsing it to object, you should do it yourself first.
Your encoding format doesn't look familiar to me, maybe there is a parsing lib for it available. To convert it to YAML format you should consider using something like this:
`labels = labels.replace("='[{", ":\n- ").replace(", ", "\n- ").replace("}]'", "")`

Comment: out_file.write will not work because in my codebase, this result actually is just one element of what eventually gets dumped into a yaml file.   

I see you edited your answer, but I did see the original answer which mentioned using safeload.   One issue is that the value couldn't be loaded into yaml, however safe_load did end up being a vital part of the solution i came up with.

Comment: @Jashua Yes, you can use yaml.safe_load() after cibverting the string to YAML format.